# Start service in blackberry 10 application

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am new to Blackberry 10 application development and I am developing an application that can run as a service in background and start another application at particular interval. I want to know is it possible to create services that can run in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the documents that describe Android features that are not supported by the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps on BlackBerry 10. =)

[Software Features](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html)

> No support to run services in the background. Applications can run
>   services only while the user runs them, either in fullscreen or in
>   thumbnail mode

Answer (score 3):

Running application or any service in background is currently not supported by BlackBerry 10 sdk.

It will be supported in upcoming sdk release. [Check out Headless apps in roadmap](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/)

Comment: since headless was introduced with bbos 10.2, this is the more correct answer